# ASP.NET View PDF in the webpage

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to put a pdf document in a a web page. But instead of viewing this in the web page, when this page is called it ask's if we want to save/download an then open this in Adobe with the printer dialog open.

Javascript which calls this page load function

```
 window.open("http://localhost:1843/PrintDocument.aspx?DocumentId="+id+"&Year="+year+"&Location="+loc);
```

ASPX CODE BEHIND , Page load function:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"; 
            string yr = Request.QueryString["Year"].ToString();
            string Dyr = Convert.ToDateTime(yr).Year.ToString();
            string Location = Request.QueryString["Location"].ToString();
            string DocumentID = Request.QueryString["DocumentId"].ToString();    
            string PDFFile = string.Format(@"\\abc\def\pqr\{0}\{1}\{2}.pdf", Dyr, Location.Substring(0, 4), Location.Substring(4, 4));
            //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=document.pdf");
            Response.WriteFile(PDFFile);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was testing this code on firefox and it was missing the PDF plugin. Once I added this plugin
it started working with my code.  So when ever you are working with PDF on firefox , please make sure that you have PDF plugin.

Comment: Or better is when there is a broken PDF install.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible versions.

For example you can use the easiest way, like

```
Response.Clear();

string filePath = ur file path on the server 

Response.contentType = "application/pdf";

Response.WriteFile(filePath);
```

It was already discussed [HERE](http://forums.asp.net/t/1020921.aspx). You can find other options also.
Also check [HERE](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/PDF-View-Custom-Control.aspx) and [HERE](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread125609.html)

Also you can use custom control : [PDF Control](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Examples/Pdf-Control.zip)